# How to construct a controlled $V$ gate in qiskit?

Tags: programming, qiskit, quantum-gate, quantum-circuit

I have come across most of the quantum circuit which contains gate such as controlled $V$ and $V^{\dagger}$ but I dont know how to code it in Qiskit.

[image: The above image is the zplg gate circuit]

Comment: What's the V gate again? :)

Comment: @Cryoris I think $V$ gate in this case should be $Rx(\pi/2)$. Look at section 1.2 here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.03962.pdf  But hopefully the OP can clarify.

Comment: Illustration seems to come from [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/271995106_Novel_designs_for_fault_tolerant_reversible_binary_coded_decimal_adders) paper. I do not have access to it, could someone check it and verify it is really a $Rx(\pi /2)$ ?

Comment: @BrockenDuck The image is indeed coming from that paper. It is Figure 21 to be specific. On page 5, section 1.2 of the paper, it is stated that " $V$ is a square root of the NOT gate".  And $R_X^2(pi/2)$  is indeed equivalent to $X$ up to an overall phase....

Comment: But overall phase does matter in controlled gate.... that is $Controlled-U$ is not the same as $Controlled-e^{i\theta}U$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$V$ is the square root of $X$. That is,

\begin{align*}
V = \sqrt X = \frac{1}{2}\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{1 + i}&{1 - i}\\
{1 - i}&{1 + i}
\end{array}} \right)
\end{align*}

It is implemented in Qiskit with the name [$SX$](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.SXGate.html). So, the circuit in your question is easy to implement:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.circuit.library import SXdgGate

qc = QuantumCircuit(4)

qc.cx(2, 3)
qc.cx(0, 3)

qc.csx(1, 2)
qc.cx(0, 1)

csxdg_gate = SXdgGate().control()
qc.append(csxdg_gate, [1, 2])

qc.csx(0, 2)
qc.cx(2, 0)

qc.draw('mpl')
```

[image]

Comment: [source code](https://www.github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/tree/main/qiskit%2Fcircuit%2Flibrary%2Fstandard_gates%2Fsx.py) for the $SX$ gate

Answer (score 2):

I don't remember what is the V-gate, sorry, but I created something that you can easily change so you can put any gate you like.

The idea is to create the gate and then use the [ControlledGate](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.ControlledGate.html) to create the control you like. I also put on there an example of how to create a control from an already existing gate, notice you can put more than 1 control.

```
from qiskit.circuit import Gate
from qiskit.circuit.library import HGate
from qiskit.quantum_info import Operator
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit

my_control_gate = Operator([[1.,0],[0,-1]]).to_instruction().control(1)
circuit = QuantumCircuit(3)
circuit.append(my_control_gate, [0,1])
circuit.barrier()
H_control = HGate().control(2)
circuit.append(H_control, [0,2,1])
circuit.draw()
```

This code will give you this :

[image: Controlled Gates]

Hope it helps, tell me if you need precision :)