# How does the V gate perform modular exponentiation?

Tags: quantum-gate, modular-exponentiation

The [V gate](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/18107/how-to-construct-a-controlled-v-gate-in-qiskit) is defined such that $V^2=X$:

$$ V|0\rangle = \frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix} 1+i&1-i\\1-i&1+i\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix} = \frac{1+i}{2}|0\rangle + \frac{1-i}{2}|1\rangle$$

$$ V|1\rangle = \frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix} 1+i&1-i\\1-i&1+i\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix} = \frac{1-i}{2}|0\rangle + \frac{1+i}{2}|1\rangle$$

According to [this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/6842/is-there-a-simple-formulaic-way-to-construct-a-modular-exponentiation-circuit), modular exponentiation can be implemented via the V gate as follows:

$$ V|x\rangle|y\rangle = |x\rangle|xy\mod{N}\rangle$$

I am not quite familiar with this notation. Suppose $x=5=[0101]$ and $y=3=[0011]$,

Does the above equation translate to something like

$$ V|0101\rangle|0011\rangle = |0101\rangle|1111\mod{N}\rangle$$

?

I also cannot see how is the V gate mathematically related to the modular exponentiation operation

$$a^x = 1 \mod{N}$$

?

---

Ref:

[image]

Modular exponentiation as application of phase estimation (Nielson & Chuang):

[image]

Comment: Do you have a reference? Something is unclear here, is $V$ acting on a single qubit or many?

Comment: @Mauricio Upon further checking, I don't think V refers to $\sqrt X$? For reference, the factorization of 3x5=15 (https://www.researchgate.net/figure/A-gate-by-gate-breakdown-of-the-7-qubit-Shors-algorithm-circuit-used-for-factorising-15_fig1_327882177) uses these V gates... what are these gates?

Comment: That reference says it is using the notation of Nielsen Chuang, have you checked it? Also note that those are controlled gates not just $V$

Comment: Check also https://www.nature.com/articles/414883a

Comment: @Mauricio V does seem to mean $\sqrt X$ in Nielson & Chuang. Also, they gave a presentation of factoring as application of phase estimation (attached above), but i am not familiar with the notation used (what is a $|x^k \mod{N}\rangle$ concretely?)

Comment: $V$ is just a notation that is often used for some generic unitary. You cannot assume that just because in *some* place $V$ is found to be something specific, that it's the same everywhere else. I certainly wasn't using it in that way in the answer of mine that you link to.

Comment: @DaftWullie thank you. it seems that this type of circuit works specifically for 1 specific $a$ and 1 specific $N$, right? but in a general purpose factoring machine, $N$ changes per problem, and $a$ changes even more, several times per problem (per trial guess number), right? So i'm not quite clear how can this type of hard-coded circuits be useful for a general purpose factoring machine?

Comment: You just design the circuit for the specific $a$ and $N$. This is something that can be done automatically on a classical computer.

Comment: @DaftWullie ah yes! you mean the quantum circuit is really just a time sequence of instructions applied one after the other, so if the right instruction steps can be found on a classical computer then the sequential quantum gate steps can be changed as needed per individual $a$ and $N$... so the real constraint is in having enough qubit lines to accomodate the $2^n$ modulo residue bins for large 2000+ digit numbers?

Answer (score 0):

As there are no answers posted yet, I shall work partially on the question while waiting for one...

There exist a [hard-coded circuit](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/4852/why-is-this-implementation-of-the-order-finding-algorithm-not-working?rq=1) that surprisingly outputs $7 \times n \mod{15}$ correctly for all $n = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14}$ without performing any arithmetic.

$$[0000] \times 7 = [1111] \mod{15}$$

[image]

$$[0001] \times 7 = [0111] \mod{15}$$

[image]

$$[0010] \times 7 = [1110] \mod{15}$$

[image]

$$...$$

The input [0001] when iterated $2^8=256$ times through the circuit would give the repeating sequence of period 4:

$$1, 7, 4, 13, 1, 7, 4, 13, 1, 7, 4, 13, 1, 7, 4, 13,... $$

---

Phase kick-back & oscillation:

[image]

Step 1:

$$ e^{ia}|0\rangle e^{ib}|1\rangle = e^{i(a+b)}|01\rangle$$

Step 2:

$$ e^{i(a+b)}(|0\rangle + |1\rangle)|1\rangle=e^{i(a+b)}(|01\rangle+|11\rangle)$$

Step 3:

$$e^{i(a+b)}(|01\rangle+e^{ic}|11\rangle)=e^{i(a+b)}|01\rangle +e^{i(a+b+c)}|11\rangle $$

Step 4:

$$e^{i(a+b)}(|0\rangle + |1\rangle)|1\rangle +e^{i(a+b+c)}(|0\rangle - |1\rangle)|1\rangle$$
$$=e^{i(a+b)}|01\rangle + e^{i(a+b)}|11\rangle +e^{i(a+b+c)}|01\rangle - e^{i(a+b+c)}|11\rangle$$
$$=(e^{i(a+b)} + e^{i(a+b+c)})|01\rangle + (e^{i(a+b)}- e^{i(a+b+c)})|11\rangle$$
$$=\color{red}{[(e^{i(a+b)} + e^{i(a+b+c)})|0\rangle + (e^{i(a+b)}- e^{i(a+b+c)})|1\rangle]}|1\rangle$$

For any fixed random $a$ and $b$, varying $c$ contributes to a periodic oscillating relative probabilities between measuring $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ on the top qubit:

[image]

The original (lower) qubit remains unmeasured while the cloned kick-back phases can be duplicated for measurement as many times as necessary.

Suppose 10 different $c$ lines are implemented as: $$c= \{\frac{0}{10}2\pi,\frac{1}{10}2\pi,\frac{2}{10}2\pi,\frac{3}{10}2\pi,\frac{4}{10}2\pi,\frac{5}{10}2\pi,\frac{6}{10}2\pi,\frac{7}{10}2\pi,\frac{8}{10}2\pi,\frac{9}{10}2\pi\}$$

Then $a+b=-c$ is manifested in equal probabilities of measuring $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ on the cloned qubits, thereby $a+b$ has been estimated to an accuracy of $\frac{2\pi}{10}$.

If $a$ is defined as having a baseline $0$ angle, then $b$ angle has been estimated relative to $a$.

---

Verification of quantum phase estimation algorithm:

[image]

Define

$$U = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & e^{i\phi}\end{bmatrix}$$

Then,

Step 0:

$$ |0000\Psi\rangle $$

Step 1:

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt2}(|0\rangle+|1\rangle)\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(|0\rangle+|1\rangle)\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(|0\rangle+|1\rangle)\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(|0\rangle+|1\rangle)|\Psi\rangle$$

$$=\frac{1}{2^2}(|0000\Psi\rangle + |0001\Psi\rangle + |0010\Psi\rangle + |0011\Psi\rangle + |0100\Psi\rangle + |0101\Psi\rangle + |0110\Psi\rangle + |0111\Psi\rangle + |1000\Psi\rangle + |1001\Psi\rangle + |1010\Psi\rangle + |1011\Psi\rangle + |1100\Psi\rangle + |1101\Psi\rangle + |1110\Psi\rangle + |1111\Psi\rangle)$$

Step 2, 3, 4, 5:

$$=\frac{1}{4}(|0000\Psi\rangle + e^{(i2\pi\phi)1}|0001\Psi\rangle + e^{(i2\pi\phi)2}|0010\Psi\rangle + e^{(i2\pi\phi)3}|0011\Psi\rangle + e^{(i2\pi\phi)4}|0100\Psi\rangle + e^{(i2\pi\phi)5}|0101\Psi\rangle + e^{(i2\pi\phi)6}|0110\Psi\rangle + e^{(i2\pi\phi)7}|0111\Psi\rangle + e^{(i2\pi\phi)8}|1000\Psi\rangle + e^{(i2\pi\phi)9}|1001\Psi\rangle + e^{(i2\pi\phi)10}|1010\Psi\rangle + e^{(i2\pi\phi)11}|1011\Psi\rangle + e^{(i2\pi\phi)12}|1100\Psi\rangle + e^{(i2\pi\phi)13}|1101\Psi\rangle + e^{(i2\pi\phi)14}|1110\Psi\rangle + e^{(i2\pi\phi)15}|1111\Psi\rangle)$$

$$= \frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=0}^{15}e^{i2\pi\phi k}|k\Psi\rangle$$

Define inverse quantum fourier transform of $|k\rangle$ as:

$$ |k\rangle = \frac{1}{4}(|0\rangle + e^{-i2k\pi \frac{1}{16}}|1\rangle + e^{-i2k\pi \frac{2}{16}}|2\rangle + e^{-i2k\pi \frac{3}{16}}|3\rangle + + e^{-i2k\pi \frac{4}{16}}|4\rangle + ...)$$

$$ \boxed{|k\rangle = \frac{1}{4}\sum_{x=0}^{15} e^{-i2k\pi \frac{x}{16}}|x\rangle}$$

Step 6:

Substituting $|k\rangle$ with inverse fourier transform, and let $\Psi = a|1\rangle$ for some complex number $a$:

$$= \frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=0}^{15}e^{i2\pi\phi k}\frac{1}{4}\sum_{x=0}^{15} e^{-i2k\pi \frac{x}{16}}a|x1\rangle$$
$$= \frac{a}{16}\sum_{k=0}^{15}\sum_{x=0}^{15} e^{i2\pi\phi k}e^{-i2k\pi \frac{x}{16}}|x1\rangle$$
$$= \frac{a}{16}\sum_{k=0}^{15}\sum_{x=0}^{15} e^{i2\pi k(\phi-\frac{x}{16})}|x1\rangle$$

which may be computed numerically to estimate $a$, since $a$ and $\sum_{k=0}^{15}\sum_{x=0}^{15} e^{i2\pi k(\phi-\frac{x}{16})}$ will interfere differently for each state coefficient $x$.

---

Verification of order finding algorithm:

[image]

Let N = 15. Then,

$$L = 4$$
$$t = 2(4)+1+1=10$$
$$|0...\rangle = |0000000000\rangle$$
$$|1...\rangle = |1111\rangle$$

Step 1:

$$ |00000000001111\rangle$$

Step 2:

$$\frac{1}{256}\sum_{j=0}^{255}|j 1111\rangle\\=\frac{1}{256}(|0000000000\color{red}{1111}\rangle + |0000000001\color{red}{1111}\rangle + |0000000010\color{red}{1111}\rangle + ...)$$

Step 3:

$$\frac{1}{256}\sum_{j=0}^{255}|j (X^j \mod{15})\rangle$$

for freely chosen $X$ having no common factors with 15.

Let X = 2.

$$=\frac{1}{256}\sum_{j=0}^{255}|j (2^j \mod{15})\rangle$$
$$=\frac{1}{256}(|0000000000 (2^0 \mod{15})\rangle + |0000000001 (2^1 \mod{15})\rangle + |0000000010 (2^2 \mod{15})\rangle + |0000000011 (2^3 \mod{15})\rangle + |0000000100 (2^4 \mod{15}) + ...)$$
$$=\frac{1}{256}(|0000000000\color{red}{0001}\rangle + |0000000001\color{red}{0010}\rangle + |0000000010\color{red}{0100}\rangle + |0000000011\color{red}{1000}\rangle + |0000000100\color{red}{0001}\rangle + ...)$$
$$=|0\rangle |1\rangle + |1\rangle |2\rangle + |2\rangle |4\rangle + |3\rangle |8\rangle + |4\rangle |1\rangle + |5\rangle |2\rangle + |6\rangle |4\rangle + |7\rangle |8\rangle + |8\rangle |1\rangle + |9\rangle |2\rangle + |10\rangle |4\rangle + |11\rangle |8\rangle +|12\rangle |1\rangle+|13\rangle |2\rangle + |14\rangle |4\rangle + |15\rangle |8\rangle $$

$$=(|0\rangle  + |4\rangle  + |8\rangle  + |12\rangle )|1\rangle \\+ 
(|1\rangle  + |5\rangle  + |9\rangle  + |13\rangle )|2\rangle \\+ 
(|2\rangle  + |6\rangle + |10\rangle  + |14\rangle )|4\rangle \\+
(|3\rangle + |7\rangle  + |11\rangle  +|15\rangle)|8\rangle $$

Step 4:

Measure last 4 qubits to collapse them, leaving the unmeasured first 10 qubits state into exactly one of $|1\rangle, |2\rangle, |4\rangle, |8\rangle$:

$$|1\rangle \rightarrow \color{blue}{|0\rangle  + |4\rangle  + |8\rangle  + |12\rangle} $$

$$|2\rangle \rightarrow  \color{blue}{|1\rangle  + |5\rangle  + |9\rangle  + |13\rangle}$$

$$|4\rangle \rightarrow \color{blue}{|2\rangle  + |6\rangle + |10\rangle  + |14\rangle }$$

$$|8\rangle \rightarrow  \color{blue}{|3\rangle + |7\rangle  + |11\rangle  +|15\rangle}$$

In any of the sub cases, Fourier transform will find the same frequency of $4$, which implies $2^4 = 1 \mod{15}$.

Step 5:

The factoring algorithm will proceed classically by checking for the greatest common divisor next.